# Could i use differents node versions between my project and specific library?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, npm

i will try to give you a little of context.

With my team we are trying to migrate MUI v3 to v4 in a reactJs project. We did it with the project itself and it works! but, some kind of problems came up when we navigated to certain windows that use a certain library to work.
This library was developed by other guy that is not in the company anymore and we are not in touch neither, but, we have access to the library GitHub repository, them are two actually.

https://github.com/rjpizarro/forms

https://github.com/rjpizarro/make-request

i've never had to do this so, i decided to clone the project then install the dependencies and run it.
I'm using nvm so in that moment i was working with node v12 and i got some errors when i executed the npm start ("start": "webpack --watch").
If i use node 10 the scrips runs perfectly but in the entire project we are using node 12 so i'm not sure what is the problem here.

i'm wonder if it could be a problem when i'll try to migrate from MUI v1 to v4 and use the modified library into my project again, or in first place, why its working rigth now?

Anyway i just wanted to know, just if i need it, Could i use different versions of node in a library and then use other newer version into the entire project?

Could this make some negatives effect into my entire project?

Which is the best way to migrate MUI into this library and put it in my project again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each nodejs process (including all the modules/libraries it loads) has exactly one version of nodejs running.  It isn't possible to have two separate versions of nodejs in the same process each running different parts of the code.

You could make two separate nodejs apps that each run under a different version of nodejs that communicate with each other via some interprocess communication, but they have to be two separate applications/processes.

If you want to run everything in one process (on one version of nodejs), then you will need to test and fix all your libraries to run on that one version of nodejs.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your fast reply!
This is confusing  because when my entire project is using node v12 and MUI v3 the whole thing works just fine. But when i use the v4 of MUI on it, some stuff stops working into this specific library that use MUI V1. What is your recomendation to make it work?

Comment: @NAm - You will have to follow up with the specific library that is trying to use MUI v1 and see exactly what the problem there is.  I would be surprised if projects are supported where different components are using different versions of MUI.  That's usually not a tested or supported configuration for libraries.  Sometimes it might work (it really depends upon the implementation of the library) and sometimes it will not because of incompatibilities between the ways that different versions of the same library do things.

Comment: So, in a way, i was lucky until now hahah. Thank you!